# What does this line in bash mean? ". ~/some_env database_name"

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash
#
. ~/some_env database_name
```

The code looks just like the above, and every time I try to run it in bash I get an error that the file or directory doesn't exist. If I make the directory it complains that I am using a directory. If I make a file, it complains that "filename is not a function".

What does this line of code do?
It's very hard to figure out what the line does because the search string is so short.

Also, I am very new to bash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.` is shorthand for [source](http://ss64.com/bash/period.html), so this command just executes the contents of `~/some_env` with parameter `database_name`. Note that `source` executes the contents of the named file within the current shell context (i.e. not in a sub-shell) and it does not matter if the named file is not executable. If you don't have a file named `some_env` in your home directory or a file named `database_name` in your current working directory then you will get an error message.

Comment: "executes the contents" doesn't make it clear how source differs from running something in an external process.

Comment: @Charles: true - although I did link to full info on `source` - I'll expand a little.

Comment: Ah I should have realized I was just executing a file.

Comment: @PaulR, you've just closed my, very similar to this [question]( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20525770/i-am-not-surposed-to-source-etc-profile). I've programmed 30 years on sh/bash and don't know the answer to it. Do you care to explain why? The questions that you don't answer - you close?

Answer (score 4):

`.` runs the script `some_env` as if you typed the commands inside in your current shell. This is called sourcing, and is different from running it as a normal script, because it can set environment variables, create functions, etc. that will be present in your current shell after running that command.

`database_name` is the first argument, and will be available as `$1` inside the script.

If you don't have a file at `~/some_env`, you will get an error as there will be nothing to run; it's also possible that something inside the script references a file that doesn't exist. You may need to post more details about the script.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know that `~` references your home directory?  If the script is coming from another user, when he ran it it was finding the file some_env in his home directory.  When you run it, that file is either not there or not containing what the script expects.

Comment: Yes, I tried just running cd ~/ and realized it referenced the home directory of my specific user. Thanks, but I'm sure you realize that's not what I was asking specifically.